# Simulate Click on non-focused window

Tags: vba, mouseevent, sendmessage, hwnd

I know this has been asked before but none answer my question because all of the others use (x,y) coordinated. I was wondering if there was a way to not have to be focused on a window yet simulate a mouse click on that windows button, all with just having the buttons hWnd. 
Here is the code that I am using but it won't work.

```
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr


Sub ClearCon()
    Dim PARENThwnd As IntPtr
    Dim CHILDhwnd As IntPtr
    PARENThwnd = FindWindow(Nothing, "ET Console")
    CHILDhwnd = FindWindowEx(PARENThwnd, Nothing, "Button", "Clear")

    SendMessage(CHILDhwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    SendMessage(CHILDhwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
End Sub
```

And this is the error I get when I put a watch on the SendMessage functions:

```
    SendMessage Argument not specified for parameter 'hWnd' of 'Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As System.IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As System.IntPtr, lParam As System.IntPtr) As System.IntPtr'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Didn't you get any answer on this?!
I have the same issue now!